# Временное хранение данных python

Tags: python, viber

Необходимо сохранить в базу ссылку на видео если пользователь присылает видеосообщение

```
# пользователь прислал видео сообщение 
elif mess_type == 'video': # проверка является ли сообщение видео?
video_url = viber_request.message.media() #берем ссылку на видео из сообщения

#тут надо кудато временно сохранить сылку чтобы после слудующего ответа сохранить ее в базу
#пишем ему ответ

viber.send_messages(viber_request.sender.id, [ 
  TextMessage(text='Какому заданию соответствует видео?', 
  keyboard=keyboard_exercises) 
  ]) 

#пользователь с меню вайбер вводит ответ например 1_video

elif viber_request.message.text == '1_video':
video_url = нужно узнать ссылку на видео из предыдущего сообщения

   User.query.filter_by(viber_id=viber_id).update({'ex_1': video_url}) 
   db.session.commit()
```

Как можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - объявляем переменную глобально как словарь. В неё и пишем:

```
video_urls={}

def get_message():
    global video_urls
    #...
    video_urls['viber_request.sender.id'] = viber_request.message.media()
    #...
    elif viber_request.message.text == '1_video':
        video_url = video_urls['viber_request.sender.id']
```

Или есть какие-то дополнительные сложности?

Comment: Тут можно и не писать `global video_urls`, т.к. вы только обращаетесь к переменной, а не пытаетесь указать новую ссылку на объект (`video_urls = {...`). Хотя, `global ` может подсказать, что тут глобальная переменная используется и это будет помощью программисту :)

Comment: @gil9red Совершенно согласен. Я и сам частенько это не делаю. За что был пару раз "укушен"... Лучше уж перебдеть в этом случае. Да и понимать программу, по идее, становится легче